# static or dynamic conference rooms asterisk?

Tags: ubuntu, asterisk

Asterisk - conference calls

1. Which one is the better and why? Creating static conference rooms for each sip client or creating dynamic ones?
2. Can a sip client choose if he wants to call directly another sip client or to call directly in his conference room?

Need help. I am using meetme with asterisk 1.8.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No better way.

Dynamic was is new one. Was not accesable before. Note,dynamic require more dialplan checks and more complex in implementing if you advanced features of conference.

If both way is working, load is same.

All "choice" have to be done by dialplan. So yes, choose is posible, but you have program it.

I am recomending you read first "Asterisk the future of telephony" book or even hire developer.

It looks like your level not allow create application for asterisk yet.

Comment: so it's ok if i create a conference room for each client? and secondly is it possible to call from one conference room to another conference room?

Comment: Yes. It is ok create as many room as u want. To bidge 2 conference room together you have use call-file or originate call. Put one leg of call to one conference(via dialplan), put second leg in other conference. http://www.voip-info.org/wiki/view/Asterisk+Call+Files.

Comment: thx a lot! What else can I do if each client has his own room conference?

Comment: if i have a sip client that has hs conference room. Is it possible for him to send request messages for the people how this person wants to add in his conference room? I MEAN can i set in a confererence room the people that i want to join in with me in my conference room? how to do that/

Comment: Conference just do conference. If you want any operation, you need create dialplan for that. You can specify context to be executed on call press, after that you have put in it script which will do call-file to dialout and invite to conference. i am sorry, it is not posible "just describe" how to do that. it require ALOT of code

Comment: thx for your answer. can you give me sole links to examples that describe what you'v said?

Comment: when you say invite to conference you mean call to confernce or send an sms to conference?

Comment: i've successful created a call file. How can I set asterisk to execute the files from outgoing folder just when the sip client whats to open his conference room?

Comment: i already give you link with example. Please read carefully.it have examples of ALL u asking fore